# When is an interface with a default method initialized?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default-method

While searching through the Java Language Specification to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation#23093470), I learned [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)

> Before a class is initialized, its direct superclass must be
> initialized, **but interfaces implemented by the class are not
> initialized.** Similarly, the superinterfaces of an interface are not
> initialized before the interface is initialized.

For my own curiosity, I tried it and, as expected, the interface `InterfaceType` was not initialized.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InterfaceType foo = new InterfaceTypeImpl();
        foo.method();
    }
}

class InterfaceTypeImpl implements InterfaceType {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("implemented method");
    }
}

class ClassInitializer {
    static {
        System.out.println("static initializer");
    }
}

interface InterfaceType {
    public static final ClassInitializer init = new ClassInitializer();

    public void method();
}
```

This program prints

```
implemented method
```

However, if the interface declares a `default` method, then initialization does occur. Consider the `InterfaceType` interface given as

```
interface InterfaceType {
    public static final ClassInitializer init = new ClassInitializer();

    public default void method() {
        System.out.println("default method");
    }
}
```

then the same program above would print

```
static initializer  
implemented method
```

In other words, the `static` field of the interface is initialized ([step 9 in the Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)) and the `static` initializer of the type being initialized is executed. This means that the interface was initialized.

I could not find anything in the JLS to indicate that this should happen. Don't get me wrong, I understand that this should happen in case the implementing class doesn't provide an implementation for the method, but what if it does? Is this condition missing from the Java Language Specification, did I miss something, or am I interpreting it wrongly?

Comment: My guess would be - such interfaces considered abstract classes in terms of initialization order. I wrote this as a comment as I'm not sure whether this is correct statement :)

Comment: It should be in section 12.4 of the JLS, but does not appear to be there.  I'd say it's missing.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is a very interesting issue!

It seems like [JLS section 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) ought to cover this definitively. However, the behavior of Oracle JDK and OpenJDK (javac and HotSpot) differs from what's specified here. In particular, the Example 12.4.1-3 from this section covers interface initialization. The example as follows:

```
interface I {
    int i = 1, ii = Test.out("ii", 2);
}
interface J extends I {
    int j = Test.out("j", 3), jj = Test.out("jj", 4);
}
interface K extends J {
    int k = Test.out("k", 5);
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(J.i);
        System.out.println(K.j);
    }
    static int out(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println(s + "=" + i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Its expected output is:

```
1
j=3
jj=4
3
```

and indeed I get the expected output. However, if a default method is added to interface `I`,

```
interface I {
    int i = 1, ii = Test.out("ii", 2);
    default void method() { } // causes initialization!
}
```

the output changes to:

```
1
ii=2
j=3
jj=4
3
```

which clearly indicates that interface `I` is being initialized where it wasn't before! The mere presence of the default method is enough to trigger the initialization. The default method doesn't have to be called or overridden or even mentioned, nor does the presence of an abstract method trigger initialization.

My speculation is that the HotSpot implementation wanted to avoid adding class/interface initialization checking into the critical path of the `invokevirtual` call. Prior to Java 8 and default methods, `invokevirtual` could never end up executing code in an interface, so this didn't arise. One might think this is  part of the class/interface preparation stage ([JLS 12.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3.2)) which initializes things like method tables. But perhaps this went too far and accidentally did full initialization instead.

I've [raised this question](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2014-April/008733.html) on the OpenJDK compiler-dev mailing list. There's been a [reply from Alex Buckley](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2014-April/008734.html) (editor of the JLS) in which he raises more questions directed at the JVM and lambda implementation teams. He also notes that there's a bug in the spec here where it says "T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked" should also apply if T is an interface. So, it might be that there are both specification and HotSpot bugs here.

***Disclosure***: I work for Oracle on OpenJDK. If people think this gives me an unfair advantage at getting the bounty attached to this question, I'm willing to be flexible about it.

Comment: I asked for official sources. I don't think it gets more official than this. Give it two days to see all developments.

Comment: @StuartMarks "*If people think this gives me an unfair advantage etc*" => we are here to get answers to questions and this is a perfect answer!

Comment: A side note: The JVM Spec contains a description that is similar to that of the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5 This should be updated as well.

Comment: Another side note: I tried to flesh out the relevant parts from the OpenJDK in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23240269 , maybe the pointer to the `instanceKlass.cpp` is considered helpful.

Comment: @assylias and Sotirios, thanks for your comments. They, along with the 14 upvotes (as of this writing) on assylias' comment, have alleviated my concerns about any potential unfairness.

Comment: Do you know of any progress being made on this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There are a couple bugs that seem relevant, [JDK-8043275](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043275) and [JDK-8043190](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043190), and they're marked as fixed in 8u40. However, the behavior seems to be the same. There were also some JVM Spec changes intertwined with this, so perhaps the fix is something other than "restore the old initialization order."

Comment: I guess this bug has been fixed?

Answer (score 14):

The interface is not initialized because the constant field `InterfaceType.init` , which is being initialized by non constant value (method call), is not used anywhere.

It is known at compile time that constant field of interface is not used anywhere, and the interface is not containing any default method (In java-8) so there is no need to initialize or load the interface.

Interface will be initialized in following cases,

- constant field is used in your code.
- Interface contains a default method (Java 8)

In case of **Default Methods**, You are implementing `InterfaceType`. So, If `InterfaceType` will contain any default methods, It will be **INHERITED (used)** in implementing class. And Initialization will be into the picture.

But, If you are accessing constant field of interface (which is initialized in normal way), The interface initialization is not required.

Consider following code.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InterfaceType foo = new InterfaceTypeImpl();
        System.out.println(InterfaceType.init);
        foo.method();
    }
}

class InterfaceTypeImpl implements InterfaceType {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("implemented method");
    }
}

class ClassInitializer {
    static {
        System.out.println("static initializer");
    }
}

interface InterfaceType {
    public static final ClassInitializer init = new ClassInitializer();

    public void method();
}
```

In above case, Interface will be initialized and loaded because you are using the field `InterfaceType.init`.

I am not giving the default method example as you already given that in your question.

Java language specification and example is given in [**JLS 12.4.1**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) (Example does not contain default methods.)

---

I can not find JLS for Default methods, there may be two possibilities

- Java people forgot to consider the case of default method. (Specification Doc bug.)
- They just refer the default methods as non-constant member of
  interface. (But mentioned no where, again Specification Doc bug.)

Comment: I'm looking for a reference for the default method. The field was just to demonstrate that the interface was initialized or not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I mentioned the reason in answer for Default method...but unfortunately any JLS not found for default method yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I am looking for. I feel like your answer is just repeating things I've already stated in the question, ie. that an interface will be initialized if it contains a `default` method and a class that implements the interface is initialized.

Comment: I think java people forgot to consider the case of default method, Or they just refer the default methods as non-constant member of interface(my assumption, can not find in any doc).

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar: What do you mean by non constant field in interface? Any variable/field in interface is static final by default.

Comment: @Lokesh I mean the field which is being initialized by non-constant values...i.e. method calls. Edited the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 10):

The [instanceKlass.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/build/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.cpp#l855) file from the OpenJDK contains the initialization method `InstanceKlass::initialize_impl` that corresponds to the [Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) in the JLS, which is analogously found in the [Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) section in the JVM Spec.

It contains a new step that is not mentioned in the JLS and not in the JVM book that is referred to in the code:

```
// refer to the JVM book page 47 for description of steps
...

if (this_oop->has_default_methods()) {
  // Step 7.5: initialize any interfaces which have default methods
  for (int i = 0; i < this_oop->local_interfaces()->length(); ++i) {
    Klass* iface = this_oop->local_interfaces()->at(i);
    InstanceKlass* ik = InstanceKlass::cast(iface);
    if (ik->has_default_methods() && ik->should_be_initialized()) {
      ik->initialize(THREAD);
    ....
    }
  }
}
```

So this initialization has been implemented *explicitly* as a new **Step 7.5**. This indicates that this implementation followed some specification, but it seems that the written specification on the website has not been updated accordingly.

EDIT: As a reference, the commit (from October 2012!) where the respective step has been included in the implementation: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/build/hotspot/rev/4735d2c84362

EDIT2: Coincidentally, I found this [Document about default methods in hotspot](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ekamg/default_methods_in_hotspot.txt) which contains an interesting side note at the end:

> 3.7 Miscellaneous
>
> Because interfaces now have bytecode in them, we must initialize them at the
> time that an implementing class is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for digging this up. (+1) It may be that the new "step 7.5" was inadvertently omitted from the spec, or that it was proposed and rejected and the implementation never was fixed up to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make a case that an interface initialization should not cause any side-channel side effects that the subtypes depend on, therefore, whether this is a bug or not, or whichever way the Java fixes it, it should not matter to the application in which order interfaces are initialized.

In the case of a `class`, it is well accepted that it can cause side effects that subclasses depend on. For example

```
class Foo{
    static{
        Bank.deposit($1000);
...
```

Any subclass of `Foo` would expect that they'll see $1000 in the bank, anywhere in the subclass code. Therefore the superclass is initialized prior to the subclass.

Shouldn't we do the same thing for superintefaces as well? Unfortunately, the order of superinterfaces are not supposed to be significant, therefore there is no well defined order in which to initialize them.

So we better not establish this kind of side effects in interface initializations. After all, `interface` is not meant for these features (static fields/methods) we pile on for convenience.

Therefore if we follow that principle, it'll be no concern to us in which order interfaces are initialized.