# Null Pointer on creating an Element Wrapper

Tags: java, xml, javafx, wrapper, treetableview

I am trying to create an editable `TreeTableView` from a XML Document.
For this, i am wrapping the Elements from the Document within a class.
The Data of the Elements is stored within the attributes key and val.
My Wrapper consists of

```
private Element node;

private final StringProperty key = new SimpleStringProperty(this,  node.getAttribute("key"), "temp");
private final StringProperty val = new SimpleStringProperty(this, node.getAttribute("val"), "temp");

public ElementWrapper(Element n){
    System.out.println("creating element "+n.getNodeName());
    node = n;
}
public String getKey(){
    return key.get();
}
@Override
public String getVal(){
    return key.get();
}
public void setKey(String key){
    ((Element)node).setAttribute("key", key);
}
@Override
public void setVal(String value){
    ((Element)node).setAttribute("val", value);
}
@Override
public Element getElement(){
    return node;
}
@Override
public StringProperty keyProperty(){
    return key;
}
@Override
public StringProperty valProperty(){
    return val;
}
```

I wrote a recursive algorithm which creates the tree items and sets them with

```
TreeItem<NodeWrapper> newsub = new TreeItem<>(new ElementWrapper(current));
```

where current is the XML Element. At this Point i get a `NullPointerException` for
 `lib.ElementWrapper.<init>(ElementWrapper.java:21)`
which is the second line of the `Wrapper` class posted above.
How do i set this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
private Element node;

private final StringProperty key;
private final StringProperty val;

public ElementWrapper(Element n){
    System.out.println("creating element " + n.getNodeName());
    node = n;
    key = new SimpleStringProperty(this, node.getAttribute("key"));
    val = new SimpleStringProperty(this, node.getAttribute("val"));
}
```

Because these initializations are done before executing costructor:

```
private final StringProperty key = new SimpleStringProperty(this,  node.getAttribute("key"), "temp");
private final StringProperty val = new SimpleStringProperty(this, node.getAttribute("val"), "temp");
```

Here is nice question about initialization: [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation).
Official documentation: [Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: Well this seems to be the reason with the Null Pointer, only Problem i got now is the elements wont be set with the desired value from the Attribute. maybe i got to figure out why they only see the initial value

Comment: @chenino Sorry, could you provide more details what is wrong ?

Comment: Found the solution already, did an edit to your answer and marked it. If i set the last value on the constructur to null, values wouldnt be updated on the tree table. fixed this, now everythign is working for me. 
Thank you very much Andrii!