# android app crashes when debugging with my device

Tags: android

Hello Guys i have a strange problem 
i'm new in android apps developing 
i connected my device (Samsung A5) to Android Studio to use it instead of using an emulator.
when i ran the app

```
package com.example.bob.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.contact);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

it runs perfectly 
but when i add this : Button bc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
inside the mainActivity class it crashes when i run it .

```
package com.example.bob.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/***********************************************/
Button bc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
/**********************************************/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
       b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               setContentView(R.layout.contact);
           }
       });
    }
}
```

please explain to me where is the problem and what should i do to resolve it 
thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand how java properties are [initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation).

Next you need to understand how `findViewById` works. It lookup for views  starting from `DecorView` aka `root view` which is initialized by call to `setContentView`.

Now you will find out that

```
Button bc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

actually getting executed before `setContentView` was called. And this will cause you troubles.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer very valuable and made me understand where's my error :)

Comment: @N.Belhadj glad to help