# Java-Where does the super class object go after creating sub class object

Tags: java

When a class extends another class, the subclass constructor calls the super class constructor.

In this process there are 2 objects created, sub class and super class. My Question is what happens to this super class object through out the life cycle of subclass object?

Will it be garbage collected as the reference is of sub class?

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        System.out.println("super class constructor");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        //  super();  default added 
        System.out.println("sub class constructor");
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B ob=new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just one object. This one object is an instance of both `A` and `B`, so it needs to run `A`'s initialisation and `B`'s initialisation.

Comment: *In this process there are 2 objects created, sub class and super class*: no, not at all. A single object is being created.

Comment: Don't forget that `A` also has a super-class, `java.lang.Object` (in fact `Object` is a super-class to all reference types).

Comment: And hint: your tagging is bogus. You have a simple Java question; there is absolutely **no** need to tag this for java8 or java6.

Comment: @erwin No, not in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **one** object will be created. Therefore the code in both constructors will be executed. A sub-class has the chance to override defined behavior of its parent class.

An example will help. Imagine a class `Human` and a sub-class `Bob`:

```
class Human
class Bob extends Human
```

When creating Bob with `Bob bob = new Bob()` you will only create a Bob instance that is also a `human`. So `bob instanceOf Human` will be `true`.
As `Bob` is a `human` it makes sense that code from his and from `Human`s constructor is both executed and he also gets all methods from `Human`.

By using `super` you do not reference to a parent instance but rather to the code declared there. Imagine `Human` having a method `isAlive` and `Bob` overriding this method (he wants to be alive always).
However you want to be able to also explicitly call the `isAlive` method declared in the `Human` class though `Bob` overrode it. You do so by `super.isAlive()`. By that Java knows *ah, he wants the method from Human and not from Bob*.

Answer (score 3):

> In this process there are 2 objects created, sub class and super
>   class.

No, a single object is created : the instance of the subclass which the structure relies also on the super class.

Invoking the constructor of the super class is a requirement of the specification of the Java language. It allows to keep a consistence as subclasses should rely on the construction rules of their parent.

Comment: Not enough to arrive always the first one :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrong assumption.

Exactly **one** object is created. Yes, multiple constructor calls are going to happen (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation) for details on what exactly happens).

But right from the beginning; until the very end and `new` returning that freshly created object: only a single object comes into existence!

Comment: No. I talked to Erwin, who has now deleted his comment.

Answer (score 0):

> In this process there are 2 objects created, sub class and super class.

No, only one object is created - that of the subclass. Since subclass-superclass relationship is called "is-a", *subclass is also a superclass*.

That is why superclass methods can be called on the subclass, as long as the methods are visible. That is also why a constructor of the superclass works with the object of a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one object, constructed with its constructor and the super-constructor. The object 'ob' will inherit all properties of class B and the super-class A. If the constructor of A initialize variables for example, they will be initialized for the object 'ob' too.

Answer (score 0):

There will be only one object. super() is called to inherit the behaviour of the parent. That is why we can get the properties of parent in subclass.