# InputStream.available() generating Null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream

I'm trying to build an HTTP server, I searched the net to solve this problem, but I did not find anything like that.

I'm trying to customize an inputstream to fit read requests and HTTP responses directly from inputstream. The class, which implements an interface) that generates the null pointer exception is as follows (`n = in.available ();`):

```
public class MyHTTPInputStream extends HTTPInputStream{
 public InputStream in = null;
 public String request, reply, dataIn;      // dataIn:= data read from InputStream
 public HTTPMyRequest myRequest;
 public HTTPMyReply myReply;

 public MyHTTPInputStream(InputStream is) {
     super(is);
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @Override
 protected void setInputStream(InputStream is) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // initialize the variable
     this.in = is;
     request = null;
     reply = null;
     dataIn = null;
 }

 @Override
 public HTTPRequest readHttpRequest() throws HTTPProtocolException {
     request = readFromStream();    // read from inputStream
     System.out.println(request);
     myRequest = new HTTPMyRequest(request);
     return myRequest;
 }

 @Override
 public HTTPReply readHttpReply() throws HTTPProtocolException {
     reply = readFromStream();      // read from inputStream
     myReply = new HTTPMyReply(reply);
     return myReply;
 }

 @Override
 public void close() throws IOException {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     in.close();
 }

 public String readFromStream(){
     // read data from InputStream to String
     int n = 0;
     try {
         n = in.available();  // ******null pointer exception
         System.out.println("n: "+n);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.out.println("n: "+n);
     byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
     try {
         in.read(bytes, 0, n);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     String req = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     System.out.println(req);
     return req;
 }
}
```

In the constructor `super(is);` , refers to this in the interface:

```
public HTTPInputStream( InputStream is ) {
        this.setInputStream(is);
    }
```

This is part of my main class (`testServer`) to call up the object:

```
...
/*
*  TEST INPUTSTREAM
*/
System.out.println("_____HTTP Inputstream_____");
// read HTTP request from file request.txt
InputStream isReq = new FileInputStream(new File("src\\source\\request.txt"));
MyHTTPInputStream myIsReq = new MyHTTPInputStream(isReq);
HTTPMyRequest myRequest =(HTTPMyRequest) myIsReq.readHttpRequest();
System.out.println("_______Read request_______");
...
```

the file request.txt is in the src directory and is a simple string containing an http request, I also managed to print it on screen without problems in the main class, but in the class `readFromStream()` it generates this exception(I hid the path with ...):

> _____HTTP Inputstream_____
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   ....MyHTTPInputStream.readFromStream(MyHTTPInputStream.java:59) at
>   ....MyHTTPInputStream.readHttpRequest(MyHTTPInputStream.java:35) at
>   ....testServer.main(testServer.java:88)

Comment: Obviously `in` is `null`. Also, as far as I can tell, you should not be calling `available()`, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Done, amazing, is so embarassing this ;) thank you so much!

Comment: Note that the actual problem is caused by `public InputStream in = null;`, the explicit initialization with `null` is done **after** the invocation of the super-class constructor, overwriting the effect of its calling of `setInputStream`. See also [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation) and [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Comment: Really thank for this. But I can't vote you :(