# Why child private field is null when printing it from parent class using polymorphism in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

As far as In understand he `getS` method from child class `BB` overrides the same method from the parent class `AA`. Yet although both classes have initialized the field `s` which is returned by `getS` it's printed as `null`. Why is this happening?

This is the code:

```
public class AA {
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    private String s = "hello1";
    public AA() {
        System.out.println(service() + getS());
    }
    public static String service() {
        return "A service ";
    }
}

public class BB extends AA {
    private String s = "hello2";
    @Override
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public static String service() {
        return "B service ";
    }
}

public class CC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BB b =new BB(); //prints "A service null"
    }
}
```

Comment: The instance is only completely 'created' and 'ready to use' after termination of the constructors, not in the middle of it

Comment: tried *debugging* it?

Comment: define constructor in BB class

Comment: @Tejal no need for that. it's using the default constructor, which is exactly the same if you put it there or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we call `new SomeClass()`

1. `new` operator first creates object of `SomeClass` but that object has all its fields set to default values (0, '\0', false, null).
2. After object is created code of constructor is executed to *initialize* object properly (set its fields to proper values, and possibly do few other things).

But if class has parent class, constructor first (implicitly or explicitly) calls its `super()` constructor to ensure that all inherited fields are properly initialized, before we start using inherited methods which may depend on those fields state.

But methods are polymorphic (as long as they are not `private`, `static` or `final`). This means that when in superclass we call method which was overridden, "newest version" of code will be executed (because polymorphism uses actual type of `this` instance - returned by `new` keyword - to locate class from which it should start searching for code which should be executed - this is called late or [dynamic binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)).

So since you called `getS()` method in `AA` superclass but on `BB` instance (because that is what `new BB` created), overridden code from `BB` class was executed. Problem is that this code uses `s` declared in `BB` class, but that `s` wasn't initialized yet. Lets see how default constructor of `BB` which was invoked by `new BB()` looks like:

```
BB(){
    super(); //calls AA()
    s = "hello2"; // by default `s` holds `null` value 
                  // all initialization is moved to constructors 
                  // after superconstructor call
}
```

So

- before `s = "hello2";` is executed `s` (of BB class) holds `null`
- but before `s` is initialized to `"hello2"` `super()` is called (which internally calls `getS()`)
- since `getS()` is polymorphic code from `BB` class for that method will be executed
- but that code (from `BB`) uses `s` of BB which wasn't yet initialized, so it holds `null` and that is what you see in console.

---

Because of that it is considered bad practice (in most cases) to put in constructor methods which can be overridden. We should limit ourselves to calling methods which are not polymorphic, which means either `private` `static` or `final`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094875/2553194) you can see what is the order of initialization when you create an object. That answer is based on [Java Specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Let me copy-paste

**Object Initialization**

> 1. An object is initialized whenever a new object is created, typically
>      by evaluation of a class instance creation expression. This proceeds
>      as follows:
> 2. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter
>      variables for this constructor invocation.
> 3. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation
>      (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this),
>      then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation
>      recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor
>      invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes
>      abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 4. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor
>      invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>      this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>      constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>      superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and
>      process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using
>      these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes
>      abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same
>      reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 5. **Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers
>      for this class**, assigning the values of instance variable
>      initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>      left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source
>      code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers
>      results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed
>      and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception.
>      Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 6. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution
>      completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the
>      same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

When new BB() is executed, the default constructor is invoked

```
 public BB() {
      super();
 }
```

`super()` is stated in your code as

```
public AA() {
    System.out.println(service() + getS());
}
```

`service()` is an static method and it can not be overriden, so `A.service()` method is invoked and its result is concatenated with the result of invoking the overrided method `B.getS()`

At this point (see 5), the member `B.s` has not been initialized yet, its value is `null`.

And these are the reasons of obtaining

```
A service null
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the class hierarchy. When run the

```
 System.out.println(service() + getS());
```

It calls the overridden getS() method. In that it prints attribute s which declare in the class BB.(It not access s attribute in class AA because it private).

At that point(When running the constructor in class AA) attributes in class BB are not initialized. Because of that it prints null.

Comment: "(It not access s attribute in class AA because it private)" being private has nothing to do with it. It is because it is field and *fields are not polymorphic*. only methods are (expect private, static or final ones which is why `service()` executed code from AA not from BB).

Comment: Not in this case what I want to say is If the attribute not declared in the child class and parent class one is public it not gives the null. Just a point nothing to do with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is BB doesn't have the constructor itself. *new BB()* calls to *public AA()* then the statement below will be execute:

```
System.out.println(service() + getS());
```

then it call *inside* A, so:

- service: method of A
- getS(): return default value of s (null),

calling constructor means the object wasn't created yet, then the initialize of properties (s) still null.

Comment: Even if it did, the `AA` constructor would run first.

Comment: It did. The key point is *object wasn't created yet*, then properties were not initialised.

If you want to initialize the properties when class load, change it to class properties such as
private static String s = "hello1";

Comment: Object was created (that is what `new` operator does), it wasn't *initialized* properly yet (that is what constructor is responsible for).

Comment: BB doesn't have the constructor itself ... if that were (even possibly) so, the 'new BB()' call would make it crash.

Answer (score 0):

the other answers have pointed out the problem.

what you can is to use an instance initialiser. since it is called before the constructor body. an instance initialiser is defined as a {} block inside the class.

```
public class AA {
    private String s ;       

    { //this is an instance initialiser. 
      //it is called before the constructor body

         s = "hello1";
    }
    public AA() {
        //the constructor body is called AFTER the instance initialiser
        System.out.println(service() + getS());
    }
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public static String service() {
        return "A service ";
    }
}
```