# Why does the field declaration of a list in a child class make it null?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I currently have 2 classes with the following structure (simplified here):

```
class A
{
  private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

  public A()
  {
    init();
  }

  public void init()
  {
    myList.add("apple");
  }
}


class B extends A
{
  private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
  public B()
  {
    super();
    init();
  }

  @Override
  public void init()
  {
    myList.add("apple");
  }
}
```

I observe that in A's init(), myList is of size 0, so it was able to add "apple".
But in B's init(), myList is null, and it throws a NPE when trying to add "apple".

I know this might be something fundamental that I can't understand and I'd want to wrap my head around this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Happened to see this [Why child private field is null when printing it from parent class using polymorphism in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922077/why-child-private-field-is-null-when-printing-it-from-parent-class-using-polymor)
Is it dynamic binding? I have explicitly declared my ctor, moreover it's a list, don't they get automatically initiallized to empty lists?

Comment: "don't they get automatically initiallized to empty lists" - that happens later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, subclass initialization doesn't happen until superclass initialization is complete, to avoid having the subclass implementation see superclass components in an inconsistent state. The initialization of `B`'s `myList` field doesn't look like it's attached to any constructor, but it actually happens in any `B` constructor immediately after the superclass constructor call. This field is a completely separate field from the one declared by the superclass.

When `A`'s constructor tries to call `self.init`, it gets the override from `B`. `B`'s override tries to append to the private `myList` field in `B`, but that field isn't initialized yet.

It's generally best to avoid calling overrideable methods in a constructor.