# How to make the array size 6 in the following program by passing it like I did here?

Tags: java

I am practising dynamic coding so I want to create a list for class. I hereby Initialized a list for class and want to create an array with different length for each iteration in list. But It  doesnt initialize it like I expected instead its length says 0.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class testcase
{
   int N;
   int play []= new int [N];
   int villain[]=new int [N];
   String status;
}
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
      List<testcase> caseno=new ArrayList<testcase>();
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      int n1=1;
      //int n1=sc.nextInt();
      int i,j;
      testcase t;
      for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
      {
      int n=6;
      //int n=sc.nextInt();
      t=new testcase();
      t.N=n;
      System.out.println(t.N+" "+t.play.length);
      }
   }
}
```

The array length should print 6 instead it shows 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation)

Comment: create a `setter` method that takes and sets the `N` value.  This setter should also instantiate your `play` array

Comment: The arrays get initialized with the default value of `N` (which is `0`) when you call `new testcase()`, you probably want to accept a constructor parameter `N` and assign it from that constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a constructor which does these assignment based on the value passed.

```
// Implement your constructor something like this

public Testcase(int value) {
    this.N = value;
    play = new int [value];
    // Some more assignment based on the need
}
```

And after that, you need to create the object instance

```
int N = 6;
Testcase newTestcase = Testcase(N);
```

NOTE: Clase name should always start with a capital letter.

Try declaring these variable like `N`, `status`, `play` e.t.c as `private`. After that `assign` and `access` them using `getter()` and `setter()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a parametrized constructor in which you'll pass the value of `N` and then initilaze the arrays. Like

```
class testcase // Name should be in PASCAL 
{
   int N;
   int [] play;
   int [] villain;
   String status;

   public testcase (int n) { // Constructor 
      this.N=n;
      play = new int [N];
      villain=new int [N];
   }

}
```

And in the main methos you create object like this

```
  int n= . . .;//taking input from user
  testcase t=new testcase(n);
```

Comment: @Lino  `userAccount` is a camel case and `UserAccount` is a Pascal case. Class name should be in Pascal case and methods and member variables in camel case.

Comment: nvm then, got it mixed up