# private variable is suddenly null

Tags: java

Let's say we have a class:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {

    private AnotherObject ao = null;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        ao = new AnotherObject();
        if (ao != null) {
            log.info("NOT NULL");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSomething() {
        if (ao == null) {
            log.info("It is NULL.");
        }
        ao.doIt(); //NullPointerException here
    }
}
```

And the corresponding abstract class:

```
public class AbstractClass implements Runnable {
    Thread myThread = null;
    
    AbstractClass () {
        init();
        myThread = new Thread(this, "ThreadName");
        myThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            doSomething();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void init();
    protected abstract void doSomething();
}
```

The constructor of `MyClass` calls the parent's constructor and the parent's constructor calls the `init()` method. This `init` method initializes the `ao` variable and therefore the log shows, that this `ao` object is NOT null.

After this, the parent's constructor creates a thread and this thread will execute the `while` loop, which calls `doSomething()`. In this overridden method, the `ao` object is used, but this `ao` object is suddenly null.

Can somebody explain me the `ao` object is set and then suddenly it is null?

Comment: Not sure if that's the reason of this behaviour but passing a half-created object into another thread seems like terrible idea - you shouldn't pass `this` inside of a constructor.

Comment: @GokulNathKP no, this is not the problem here. This question is about understanding the initialisation of a class, not about the null, specifically.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private AnotherObject ao = null;
```

Remove the `= null;`.

You are initializing it by the methods invoked in the super constructor, but the initializer to null is then executed afterwards.

To be more clear, this:

```
    private AnotherObject ao = null;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }
```

is identical to this:

```
    private AnotherObject ao;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
        ao = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation), the `super` constructor is run *before* the field initialisers (i.e. `private AnotherObject ao = null;`).

Therefore, the `super();` call gets run, sets `ao` to non-null, returns, and then `private AnotherObject ao = null;` gets run, setting `ao` to null again.

This is why you should not call methods that can be overridden in subclasses in a constructor. Because at that point, `this` has not been fully initialised.