# Are the member fields in a Java class initialized in order of declaration?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a Java class, like this:

```java
public class Example {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
    private Bar bar = new Bar(this.foo);
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `bar` will always be instantiated with a `Foo` as its constructor, or is there a chance it will be instantiated with `null` instead?

Is the order in which the members of a Java class are intialized guaranteed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed.

In particular, [JLS 12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) says (emphasis added):

> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, **in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class**. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.